# MySQL SELECT from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS taking > 1 minute

Tags: mysql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = "transactions"
```

And here is how long it took:

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 36 total, Query took 61.8934 sec)
```

I'm no dba but this isn't normal, is it?  Should it be my expectation that querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA should take over a minute?  Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?  Do I need to add an index or something in order to get normal response out of this?

--- Edit to address questions

Version 5.5.30-30.2

This db is hosted by HostGator

EXPLAIN SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = "transactions"

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  COLUMNS     ALL     NULL    TABLE_NAME  NULL    NULL    NULL    Using where; Open_frm_only; Scanned 1 database
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE transactions:

```
transactions    CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `accountId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `contractId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `insertionId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `aNetCIMProfileId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `paymentProfileId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `wasSuccessful` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `amount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `resultText` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `authNetTransactionId` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `isChargedBack` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

---

```
SELECT Count( * )
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

[This also took > 1 minute]

> 1303

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = "transactions" 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydbname'
```

Same response time

```
SET global innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0;
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

(This db is hosted by HostGator)

Comment: yes, it's definitely not normal, and no you shouldn't be messing with the table structures in the mysql.* db. That's an internal DB used by mysql for pretty much everything it does. You can totally hose your setup if you start doing anything but selecting data from in there. Turn on your slow query log and start tracking down why it's taking forever for such a simple query.

Comment: can you show us `show create table....` and `explain select .....`

Comment: How many rows in information_schema.columns? i.e. `SELECT Count(*) ...`

Comment: I doubt it will make a difference, but try single quotes (i.e. `TABLE_NAME = 'transactions'`).

Comment: According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema-optimization.html), adding `TABLE_SCHEMA` in the `WHERE` might help.

Comment: Adding WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydbname' didn't help :(

Comment: [`set global innodb_stats_on_metadata=0;` might help](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/).

Comment: But querying `COLUMNS` for a mere 1300 columns should takes milliseconds.

Comment: [dba.se] might be better for this type of DB question.

Comment: I can't set the global, #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation ... This db is hosted by HostGator.

Comment: Should I just copy/paste this question over there?

Comment: No. You can flag it to be migrated (though I'm not 100% sure it should be there). Actually, if it's hosted on HostGator I'd probably try to get in contact with them first. If possible, first create a clean database and see if it does the same, if not, try to identify what caused it in your current DB.

Comment: OK I flagged it to move and I have a ticket open with HostGator

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME like  "%transactions%" 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydbname'
```

in TABLE_SCHEMA provide the database name mydbname.
On shared hosting it will take more time if you have access then it will show you the result.

Answer (score 0):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA has been known for a long time to have really bad performance if you have a lot of databases and tables.

MySQL improves the performance of I_S in each major release, so you need to upgrade as much as you can to the current version.

You should also set the server option `innodb_stats_on_metadata=0` which will help a bit. It reduces the cost of statistics collection when you query the I_S. In MySQL 5.6.6 and later, this is 0 by default.

In MySQL 8.0 they have totally redesigned the internals of the I_S, so it should gain much better performance.